# WPF Invert Slider Control

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

does anybody have a idea how to invert the direction of the standard Slider Class in WPF?
Syncfusion or Telerik have some custom Sliders, but either it's not free (Syncfusion) or the Design is not really great. So i'm looking for a Solution with the Standard .NET Class.

[image]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <Slider x:Name="Slider_Speed_P2" Width="150" Margin="5" TickFrequency="10" TickPlacement="BottomRight" Maximum="150" ValueChanged="Slider_Speed_P2_ValueChanged" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Title_Slider_Speed_P2" Text="Ladung"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Val_Slider_Speed_P2" Text="0"/>
     </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Basically the Minimum should be on the right, and the maximum should be on the left.

I already tried to switch the Maximum and Mimimum Properties. But then i get a System.NullReferenceException.

Comment: Set `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`.

Comment: OMG... so easy... shame on me

Answer (score 0):

I think this was answered in a comment but I can verify that answer.

Set the FLowDirection property on the slider to RightToLeft